# Drools best score is null

Tags: java, drools, drools-planner

I'm using Drools 5.4.0.CR1 and when I start with

```
...
XmlSolverFactory configurer = new XmlSolverFactory();
configurer.configure(SOLVER_CONFIG);
Solver solver = configurer.buildSolver();
solver.setPlanningProblem(initialSolution);
solver.solve();
....
```

I have this output

```
[exec:exec]
2012-04-30 11:10:46,296 [main] INFO  Solving started: time spend (169), score (-13hard/0soft), new best score (-13hard/0soft), random seed (0).
2012-04-30 11:10:46,338 [main] DEBUG     Step index (0), time spend (213), score (-12hard/0soft), new best score (null), accepted move size (10) for picked step (03-05-2012 P emp:EMPLOYEE1 => L).
2012-04-30 11:10:46,356 [main] DEBUG     Step index (1), time spend (231), score (-12hard/0soft), new best score (null), accepted move size (10) for picked step (02-05-2012 P emp:EMPLOYEE2 => S).
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.drools.planner.core.score.buildin.hardandsoft.DefaultHardAndSoftScore.compareTo(DefaultHardAndSoftScore.java:125)
    at org.drools.planner.core.score.buildin.hardandsoft.DefaultHardAndSoftScore.compareTo(DefaultHardAndSoftScore.java:27)
    at org.drools.planner.core.localsearch.decider.acceptor.tabu.AbstractTabuAcceptor.isAccepted(AbstractTabuAcceptor.java:121)
    at org.drools.planner.core.localsearch.decider.acceptor.CompositeAcceptor.isAccepted(CompositeAcceptor.java:58)
    at org.drools.planner.core.localsearch.decider.DefaultDecider.processMove(DefaultDecider.java:159)
```

This is the TRACE log:

```
2012-04-30 11:40:16,745 [main] INFO  Solving started: time spend (110), score (-13hard/0soft), new best score (-13hard/0soft), random seed (0).
    2012-04-30 11:40:16,781 [main] TRACE         Move score (-13hard/0soft), accepted (true) for move (01-05-2012 M emp:EMPLOYEE1 => P).
    2012-04-30 11:40:16,794 [main] TRACE         Move score (-13hard/0soft), accepted (true) for move (04-05-2012 L emp:EMPLOYEE2 => G).
    2012-04-30 11:40:16,794 [main] TRACE         Ignoring not doable move (01-05-2012 P emp:EMPLOYEE3 => P).
    2012-04-30 11:40:16,807 [main] TRACE         Move score (-13hard/0soft), accepted (true) for move (01-05-2012 M emp:EMPLOYEE4 => S).
    2012-04-30 11:40:16,819 [main] TRACE         Move score (-13hard/0soft), accepted (true) for move (03-05-2012 P emp:EMPLOYEE5 => A).
    ...
    2012-04-30 11:40:16,876 [main] TRACE         Move score (-12hard/0soft), accepted (true) for move (03-05-2012 P emp:EMPLOYEE21 => L).
    2012-04-30 11:40:16,876 [main] TRACE         Ignoring not doable move (01-05-2012 L emp:EMPLOYEE22 => L).
    2012-04-30 11:40:16,876 [main] TRACE         Ignoring not doable move (03-05-2012 N emp:EMPLOYEE23 => N).
    2012-04-30 11:40:16,887 [main] TRACE         Move score (-13hard/0soft), accepted (true) for move (02-05-2012 N emp:EMPLOYEE14 => TS).
    2012-04-30 11:40:16,898 [main] DEBUG     Step index (0), time spend (265), score (-12hard/0soft), new best score (null), accepted move size (10) for picked step (03-05-2012 P emp:EMPLOYEE21 => L).
```

It seems the best solution is not updated with the score value, but we defined the Solution class as your example (queens example) with getter and setter score.

Anyone have a suggestion about the "new best score" is null?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess, but does the `cloneSolution` of your solution clone the score and **all** other problem facts robustly?

I have experienced a few silent errors there.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. I'm just getting started with Drools Planner, and it turns out that I was cloning everything but the score in my Solution.

Comment: Encountered the same problem, eh?

Answer (score 0):

That line is impossible (in theory):

```
2012-04-30 ...     Step index (0), ..., new best score (null), ...
```

Debug and figure out what is producing a null Score. It's definitely a bug (in planner or in your code).

I haven't seen this before. Are you using a custom score definition?

Comment: No I use in the object Solution private HardAndSoftScore score; and in the xml file configuration <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_AND_SOFT</scoreDefinitionType>

Comment: For more informations debugging in DefaultHardAndSoftScore in the method compareTo(HardAndSoftScore other) "other" is null

Comment: Debug on `BestSolutionRecaller#extractBestSolution` when `stepScope.getScore() == null` and next, debug on `ScoreDirector#calculateScore` when that returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error as above and i am able to solve it, by simply set score in clone of my Solution class just like----->

```
public EmployeeRoster cloneSolution() {
    EmployeeRoster employeeRoster=new EmployeeRoster();
    employeeRoster.id=id;
    employeeRoster.shiftList=shiftList;
    employeeRoster.employeeList=employeeList;
    employeeRoster.score=score;
    return employeeRoster;
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.drools.planner.core.score.buildin.hardandsoft.DefaultHardAndSoftScore.compareTo(DefaultHardAndSoftScore.java:125)
>       at org.drools.planner.core.score.buildin.hardandsoft.DefaultHardAndSoftScore.compareTo(DefaultHardAndSoftScore.java:27)
>       at org.drools.planner.core.localsearch.decider.acceptor.tabu.AbstractTabuAcceptor.isAccepted(AbstractTabuAcceptor.java:121)
>       at org.drools.planner.core.localsearch.decider.DefaultDecider.processMove(DefaultDecider.java:159)
>       at org.drools.planner.core.localsearch.decider.DefaultDecider.doMove(DefaultDecider.java:129)
>       at org.drools.planner.core.localsearch.decider.DefaultDecider.decideNextStep(DefaultDecider.java:103)
>       at org.drools.planner.core.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchSolverPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchSolverPhase.java:57)
>       at org.drools.planner.core.solver.DefaultSolver.runSolverPhases(DefaultSolver.java:183)
>       at org.drools.planner.core.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:151)

Comment: The planning entity list should be deep cloned: they need new instances, so they can change independent of the original instances. See the shiftAssignementList cloning in the nurse rostering example's cloneSolution() method. The problem facts (id, employeeList) and the score field can/should indeed be just pointing to the same instance (which is more memory/cpu efficient).